# I mined in early 2010 with a cpu miner and just found my keys after forgetting all thease years, no joke need info please

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, blockchain-fork, cpu-mining, cpu

who is the best most reputable bitcoin recovery company?
I have added details and questions about our situation below
Thank you
And God Bless

what was the mining program from the devs back then? I remember a pop up kinda like a dos window and it dispalyed the key and said somthing like write this down we will not give it to you again...
I also remeber a pass sentance proram that could be used to recover somthing if you entered in you full sentace string..

I have been out of crypto since I mined a few blocks way back then and I have my keys so do i just download and sink the wallet first?
remeber I did this long ago and was hoping to located the mining program from way back then to read the readme and refresh my memory.
Also back then you could contact a dev to help you,,
thanks in advance for helping out a old man trying to pay a few bills.

Sorry guys I am old sick with cancer so I do not want anyone to think I am lazy to ask questions like this. I believe what I found are my entropy codes. I remember seeing a sit down report on CNBC back in the day about Silk Road and weather or not bitcoin was a legitimate coin ect and they spoke for a good bit at length and they told you where to download the program and I thought the blocks was 50 at a time? It was a long time ago. I had ignored the boom from a few years ago to embarrassed and to and sick to care what ever happened to my codes / keys until I found my old drives and then my old codes. I do not remember it being a pool but if it was my guy is saying it was from the dev teams or team. It was a pop up miner and it would not have much on he display in the small little box. Just your mined coin count and a splash code that said something like write this down you will not get it again and will need it for us to help you recover your coins ect.

Comment: BIP32/BIP39 (the specification for the system you are describing) did not exist in 2010, so this could not have happened.

Comment: First, please don't post any actual data. In what format did you find the keys? Did you find a `wallet.dat` file? Else, do you have the raw keys?

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the format of what you found? Is it a list of words or just a single string of letters and numbers?

Answer (score -1):

I think in late 2010 the first mining pools emerged. Could it be that you have been contributing your CPU Power to a mining pool and this was your credentials. If that was the case and you never cashed out your Bitcoin I guess you will not be able to access your coins unless you figure out which pool it was and see if the pool still exists